# Exporting django variable to python file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

Hi everybody and thank you in advance for your help.

I want to introduce a number in my home.html,  save it as variable 'n' and export it to my_calculations.py file.

```html
      <form>
        <label for='number'>Number:</label>
        <input type='number' value='Save'>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
```

Can you please explain me what should I exactly do?
I look everywhere but there's a lot of info about how to send a variable from .py to templates but not the other way round.

Comment: Literally, [part 4 of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/) talks about sending form data from the template to the view.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, now I`m trying to figure out how to import selected_choice, from views.py... def vote(), to  my_file.py.

Comment: What is my_file.py?

Comment: it`s one file I`ve created on the same level as views, models ets (will need it for my future app)   In views under the code line: selected_choice.save()    I added: global a,  a = selected_choice, print(a)    ...but how to import 'a' variable to my_file.py?

Comment: But that doesn't really make sense. What is calling the function in my_file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is a form having method post

```
<form method="POST" action="to_view( a url )">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for='number'>Number:</label>
    <input type='number' name="value">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form
```

and this form must be handled by a view example:

```
def view(request):
    # you can print the variable by print request.POST["value"]
    if request.method == "POST":
        do_Something
```

This is just a model